# Find substrings that match a list

Tags: python, pandas

How do I find all the substrings matching a `df` column value?

```
text = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog"
df = pd.DataFrame(['quick brown fox', 'jump', 'lazy dog', 'banana', 'quick fox'], columns=['value'])
results = get_matches(df, text)
# Excepted results: ['quick brown fox', 'jump', 'lazy dog']
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One option:

```
import pandas as pd

text = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog"
df = pd.DataFrame(['quick brown fox', 'jump', 'lazy dog', 'banana', 'quick fox'], columns=['value'])


def get_matches(df, text):
    return df[df['value'].apply(text.__contains__)]


res = get_matches(df, text)
print(res)
```

**Output**

```
             value
0  quick brown fox
1             jump
2         lazy dog
```

As an alternative, use [str.find](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.find):

```
def get_matches(df, text):
    return df[df['value'].apply(text.find).ne(-1)]


res = get_matches(df, text)
print(res)
```

**Output**

```
             value
0  quick brown fox
1             jump
2         lazy dog
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Is this the most efficient way to do it? Im asking because apply may not be efficient

Comment: @dasdasd The most efficient, probably not, using another types of data structure could be faster. Using cython or numba could also lead to performance gains ...

Comment: I see, any other options which you think are more efficient?

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
def get_matches(df, text): 
    return df.loc[[t in text for t in df['value']], 'value']

get_matches(df, text)
```

Output:

```
0    quick brown fox
1               jump
2           lazy dog
Name: value, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 0):

```
List=[]
for a in df.value:
    if a in text:
        print(a)
        List.append(a)
print(List)
```